# Load previous image before original one using UIL

Tags: universal-image-loader

Is possible to load an image (logo) before loading the original image using Universal Image Loader?

How would be the implementation in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the configuration, using DisplayImageOptions. Got it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DisplayImageOptions in the field 'showImageOnLoading':

> IMAGE_OPTIONS = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() //
>           .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loader) //
>           .resetViewBeforeLoading(false) //
>           .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565) //
>           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT) //
>           .delayBeforeLoading(500) //
>           .cacheOnDisc(true) //
>           .cacheInMemory(true) //
>           .build();